# Counting the number of occurrences of a string in a column in R

Tags: r, countif

I have a column containing different strings which are repeated along the column. I wanted to create another column which will basically sum up the number of occurrences of strings and fill this column with the number. This is equivalent to using countif function in excel.

Comment: Have a look at `table`

Comment: Do you want just the number of occurrences for each unique string, or the number of occurrences up to that cell ? e.g. col=`A,A,B,A,B` --> you want `A=3,B=2` or a column saying :  `1,2,1,3,2` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44259842/edit

Comment: Do you want just the number of occurrences for each unique string, or the number of occurrences up to that cell ? e.g. col=A,A,B,A,B --> you want A=3,B=2 or a column saying : 1,2,1,3,2 ?

I want the later thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
s <- c("aaa","aab","aba","abb","bbb")
look_for_what <- "aa"
length(s[grep(look_for_what,s)])
# 2
look_for_what <- "a"
length(s[grep(look_for_what,s)])
# 4
```